# How to use lambda function just in null rows of a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I am trying to put 0 or 1 in place of the null rows of a column using lambda function, but my code doesn't make any changes in the data.

```
df[df['a'].isnull()]['a']=df[df['a'].isnull()].apply(lambda x:1 if (x.b==0 and x.c==0) else 
                                                      0,axis=1)
```

Where I am wrong in this??
[sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Auxj.png)

Comment: Please add input and output, or at least some toy data

Comment: `df[df['a'].isnull()]` makes a copy `df[df['a'].isnull()]['a']` accesses the column __in that copy__. Then the copy gets thrown away since there are no references to it any longer [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/15497888) use `df.loc[df['a'].isnull(), 'a'] = ...` as outlined in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20627316/15497888)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `loc` to specifically fill the null value rows in your DataFrame. When you're using the `apply` method you can use it on the  entire DataFrame, you do not need to filter for NULL values there. The `loc` will take care of only filling the rows which meet the NULL condition. This should work :

```
df['a'].loc[df['a'].isnull()] = df.apply(lambda x:1 if (x.b==0 and x.c==0) else 
                                                  0,axis=1)
```

Comment: In this code only null values are treated and stored in new_df, but then how should I put these replaced values back in my original data frame i.e df ??

Comment: @Akansha I have edited my answer and tested it. Hope it works for you.